# Is there an easy way to render an array of list items?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am currently developing in React JS.

I want to render a `ul` with all the items in the array as a seperate `li`.

```
let listItems;
let listItem;
while (true){
     listItem = prompt("Enter a list item or press cancel to exit.");
     if(!listItem){
          break; 
     }
     listItems.push(listItem);
}

ReactDOM.render(
     <div>
        <ul>
          <li>{...listItems}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>, 
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

The above doesn't work. The compiler gives an error saying that 'Spread children are not supported in React.'

How can I do this easily?

Comment: You can read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, you would use a the `map` method to map through each item in the array and render out the appropriate JSX:

```js
let listItems = [];
let listItem;
while (true) {
  listItem = prompt("Enter a list item or press cancel to exit.");
  if (!listItem) {
    break;
  }
  listItems.push(listItem);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <ul>
      {listItems.map(item => (
        <li>{item}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-mapping-in-react-k2j2m